# Why does wget return a HTTP 403 error to download openSSH pet?

Tags: command-line, wget, openssh, puppy-linux

I am trying to learn how I would get `OpenSSH` using the command line.

I found a `*.pet` link on this webpage:

http://puppylinux.org/wikka/OpenSSH

which says:

> Installation Install an appropriate software package:
>
> openssh-5.2p1.pet at qcjn.no-ip.org:81/pupstuff openssh-5.1p1 client
>
> and server package thread packaged by Sven

I assumed I could use `wget` to retrieve the `*.pet` file. So I tried:

```
sh-4.1# wget -o log -v qcjn.no-ip.org:81/pupstuff/openssh-5.2p1.pet
```

Nothing appeared on screen, but the log file said:

```
--2014-06-29 18:01:33--  http://qcjn.no-ip.org:81/pupstuff/openssh-5.2p1.pet
Resolving qcjn.no-ip.org... 173.176.253.77
Connecting to qcjn.no-ip.org|173.176.253.77|:81... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2014-06-29 18:01:33 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Why was I denied access?

I was able to download and install the files using a web browser and `ppm`:

http://murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?p=234111

But I really want to learn the command line.